# How do you invoke a method on a class instance by string name?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to invoke a method on a class dynamically using  a String for the class name and a String for the method name. I am using `getattr` then invoking a method on the class. You'll have to forgive me if I am way off, I am kind of new to Python.

```
class mock:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def create(self):
        print('hello world?')
        return 'hello world'
```

then creating the instance and invoking via :

```
module = importlib.import_module('xyz.module')
instance = getattr(module, 'mock')
invoke = getattr(instance, 'create')
result = invoke()
print(result)
```

The result is something like `<object object at 0x10943ccd0>`. "hello world?" is never printed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not use something like `instance().create()`?

Comment: `instance` _isn't_ an instance, it's the class. But why are you doing _any_ of this, what's the context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed a step. The `instance` variable you have isn't actually an instance, it's the class `mock` itself. You need to call it to get an instance. Try something like this:

```
module = importlib.import_module('xyz.module')
klass = getattr(module, 'mock')       # rename this variable (avoiding keywords)
instance = klass()                    # and call the class to create an instance
method = getattr(instance, 'create')  # also renamed here, for clarity
result = method() # previously, this would have been an error (missing self argument)
print(result)     # now you should get "hello world" printed twice (once with a ?)
```

As a note, PEP 8 naming conventions would have helped you avoid the issue here. If you'd used the name `Mock` instead of `mock` for the class, it might have been a bit more obvious what kind of thing you had, after importing and `getattr`ing it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `getattr` at all; the instance returned by `import_module` is the same thing that would be implicitly bound to `xyz.module` had you used an `import` statement.

```
module = importlib.import_module('xyz.module')
result = module.mock().create()
assert result == "hello world"
```

Note that the above creates an *instance* of `mock` on which to call `create`, rather than accessing `mock.create` directly. If you have variables containing the name of the class and the method, you still need to do that, only using `getattr` this time.

```
module = importlib.import_module('xyz.module')
cls_name = 'mock'
method_name = 'create'

cls = getattr(module, 'mock')
instance = cls()
invoke = getattr(instance, 'create')
result = invoke()
assert result == "hello world"
```

Comment: thank you. I forgot to mention and will update, I wanted to invoke dynamically using strings. a string for the class name and a string for the method name.